# Restoring Jenkins from volume snapshot of JENKINS_HOME directory, requires I reset every user's password before they can login. How can I avoid this?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, restore, snapshot

Restoring Jenkins with a snapshot of the JENKINS_HOME directory requires that I reset every user's password before they can login. Why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

Is the password hashing using some information that is not stored in the JENKINS_HOME directory?

According to the following resources, restoring from a volume snapshot seems possible.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/backing-up/
https://devopscube.com/jenkins-backup-data-configurations/

**More Details:**

When I restore, I am spinning up an entire new ec2 instance from the same custom AMI that the backed up server was running.

I have Jenkins running in Ubuntu 22.04, on an AWS EC2 instance that is running the latest LTS version (2.361.2).

**Volume Configuration:**

`Root Volume` 8GB; From a custom AMI which is basically just Ubuntu 22.04 with Jenkins installed.

`Data Volume` 80GB; (Mounted at /data ) Restored from snapshot of previous identical Jenkins ec2 instance.

`JENKINS_HOME`: The root volume has a symlink at /var/lib/jenkins that points to /data/var/lib/jenkins

Jenkins seems to operate exactly as expected when doing a fresh install using this setup. When I recreate this server using a snapshot of the original data volume, all of the data is in the JENKINS_HOME directory and everything works as expected, with the exception that all user login attempts fail.

If I go through the password recovery steps in this post,

https://www.shellhacks.com/jenkins-reset-admin-password/

I am able to reset all user passwords and at that point it seems like everything is working as expected.

In general terms I suppose the question is: How do I move the JENKINS_HOME directory from one instance of Jenkins to another, in an automated fashion without losing the login credientials?